# AWS CLI Return Nested Results

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am trying to execute an AWS CLI query for EC2.  I have crafted the query below, but the triple nesting seems to be throwing things off for InstanceStatus.Details.Status.

`aws ec2 describe-instance-status --query 'InstanceStatuses[*].{InstanceId:InstanceId,AvailabilityZone:AvailabilityZone,InstanceState:InstanceState.Name,InstanceStatusDetails:InstanceStatus.Details.Status,Status:SystemStatus.Status}' --profile $PROFILE --output table`

```
|                                    DescribeInstanceStatus                                     |
+------------------+----------------------+----------------+-------------------------+----------+
| AvailabilityZone |     InstanceId       | InstanceState  |  InstanceStatusDetails  | Status   |
+------------------+----------------------+----------------+-------------------------+----------+
|  us-east-1a      |  i-asdfasdfasfdsdfsa |  running       |  None                   |  ok      |
```

If I strip off the .Status it will return the whole table which I don't want.

`aws ec2 describe-instance-status --query 'InstanceStatuses[*].{InstanceId:InstanceId,AvailabilityZone:AvailabilityZone,InstanceState:InstanceState.Name,InstanceStatusDetails:InstanceStatus.Details,Status:SystemStatus.Status}' --profile $PROFILE --output table`

```
|                        DescribeInstanceStatus                        |
+-------------------+-----------------------+----------------+---------+
| AvailabilityZone  |      InstanceId       | InstanceState  | Status  |
+-------------------+-----------------------+----------------+---------+
|  us-east-1a       |  i-asdfasdfasfdsdfsa  |  running       |  ok     |
+-------------------+-----------------------+----------------+---------+
||                        InstanceStatusDetails                       ||
|+-----------------------------------------+--------------------------+|
||                  Name                   |         Status           ||
|+-----------------------------------------+--------------------------+|
||  reachability                           |  passed                  ||
|+-----------------------------------------+--------------------------+|
```

What do I need to do to return the results of InstanceStatus.Details.Status with the rest of my query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dict structure as reminder:

```
{
    "AvailabilityZone": "eu-west-1b",
    "InstanceId": "i-00aabb11cc22dd33",
    "InstanceState": {
        "Code": 16,
        "Name": "running"
    },
    "InstanceStatus": {
        "Details": [
            {
                "Name": "reachability",
                "Status": "passed"
            }
        ],
        "Status": "ok"
    },
    "SystemStatus": {
        "Details": [
            {
                "Name": "reachability",
                "Status": "passed"
            }
        ],
        "Status": "ok"
    }
},
```

**InstanceStatus.Details** is an array. you have to tell from which element of the array you want to get the "Status" key

so, add **[0]** after **InstanceStatus.Details**

thus:

```
aws ec2 describe-instance-status --query 'InstanceStatuses[*].{InstanceId:InstanceId,AvailabilityZone:AvailabilityZone,InstanceState:InstanceState.Name,InstanceStatusDetails:InstanceStatus.Details[0].Status,Status:SystemStatus.Status}' --profile $PROFILE --output table
```

Comment: improved filter: `InstanceStatus.Details[?Name=='reachability'] | [0].Status` to be sure to catch the reachability status in case more than one element is possible